# Can anyone tell me what's wrong here in npm installation of tachyans?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

Whenever I am trying to install npm tachyons, I am getting this error. Please help me with it:

[Whenever I am trying to install npm tachyons, I am getting this error. Please help me with it:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PWlo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled tachyons when you did the npm command. Tachyons is spelled with an 'o' instead of an 'a'.

npm i --s tachyons